# Syntax for including header files in C files

Tags: c

I haven’t written much C code, but for a [Lua based library](https://github.com/deepakjois/luaharfbuzz) I am writing to interface with [Harfbuzz](http://harfbuzz.org), I needed to write some C code.

My question is about the syntax to include header files in C. I have seen three different variants in other C code that uses Harfbuzz

#### Variant 1

`#include <hb.h>`

#### Variant 2

`#include "hb.h"`

#### Variant 3

`#include "harfbuzz/hb.h"`

My question is – what is the most appropriate/correct/cross-compatible way to specify header files, when I am writing C code.

Comment: did you search SO? this post will teach you about variant 1 and 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: personally, I try to avoid variant 3 and only use it for internal dependencies that I have full control over.  Such code is always distributed as a whole since header dependency is captured in the header files (vs. configuring the toolchain search paths)

Comment: Thanks, I was really confused about Variant 3. But the answer you linked to does clarify things. So I have accepted the question as a duplicate.

Comment: #include <hb>
This form is used for system header files. It searches for a file named 'file' in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend directories to this list with the -I option while compiling your source code.